# Flutter setState() not refreshing widget when called from stateful child

Tags: flutter

I have two stateful widgets: ParentWidget and ChildWidget.

The ChildWidget has a gesture detector wrapping a container and text. When I call onTap the state of the Parent (status increased by 1) is updated properly but ***setState() is not refreshing the UI.***

I tried everything: global keys, inherited widget but nothing works.

Interestingly if I change the *ChildWidget to a stateless* one then everything start working. Any ideas would be super helpful.
pk

Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hexcolor/hexcolor.dart';

class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ParentWidgetState createState() => _ParentWidgetState();
}

class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
  int status = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Hexcolor('#1c486d'),
        title: Text(
          'Test',
        ),
      ),
      body: ChildWidget(
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            status = status + 1;
            setState(() {}); // this is the problematic piece of code.
          },
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            child: Text('PARENT:' + status.toString()),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChildWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget child;
  ChildWidget({this.child});
  @override
  _ChildWidgetState createState() => _ChildWidgetState(child);
}

class _ChildWidgetState extends State<ChildWidget> {
  Widget child;

  _ChildWidgetState(this.child);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return child;
  }
}
```

Comment: If my answe is useful, please accept it. Thanks. Otherwise let me know.

Comment: Hi Genchi, thanks for the comment. I know that in this example it is useless, however this is only a 'strawman' of a more complex I am working on where the child needs to be stateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the parent's `status` to the `ChildWidget` so that when the parent's `status` changes, the `ChildWidget`'s state changes and its build method be called.

```
body: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            status = status + 1;
          });
        },
        child: ChildWidget(status: status),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChildWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final int status;

  ChildWidget({this.status});
  @override
  _ChildWidgetState createState() => _ChildWidgetState();
}

class _ChildWidgetState extends State<ChildWidget> {
  _ChildWidgetState();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      child: Text('PARENT:' + widget.status.toString()),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: HI Mobina, that works just great! Many thanks it saved me literally hours of investigations. Out of curiosity so If I understand correctly If I rebuild the parent the child does not get rebuilt because it is stateful - and only with the modification you proposed it forces rebuild correct ?

Comment: If you rebuild the parent, the child gets rebuilt but the child of the child(which is the container) won't change. If you don't pass the container to the child, the problem is solved. @PrzemyslawKuznicki

Comment: Thanks so much again. Yes it is solve. I have marked it as answered. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Try not making the child final

```
  class ChildWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  Widget child;
  ChildWidget({this.child});

  @override
  _ChildWidgetState createState() => _ChildWidgetState(child);
  }
```

Comment: many thanks lenz - let me try and get back shortly.

Comment: Tried making it not final - but the issue still persists. Any other thoughts ?